# Are stainless steel more radiation absorption than carbon steel?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

Are stainless steel  more radiation absorption than carbon steel? and if it is so why?

Comment: What kind of radiation? What did you find by Googling and why didn't that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Stainless steel is steel with > 10.5% chromium. Since chromium has a lower atomic number than iron, it isn't obvious that adding it would improve the absorption coefficient of the alloy - which depends in part on density.

Comment: The question did not state that it was about x-rays. It could be thermal radiation, neutron radiation, radio waves...